# How do i get input from body

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a code that takes in input from the body directly and prints it in real-time on the body as well. But what happens is when I actualy type on the body (meaning in mid-air) it registers that i've typed something and the hello disappears but instead of showing what i've typed it gives me undefined in it's place. Here's the code:

```
<body id="bod" onkeypress="keypres()">

<h1 id="txt">hello</h1>
            
            <script>
                function keypres(){
                    var x = document.getElementById("bod").value;
                    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = x;
                }
            </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have a look at [keypress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeypress). Your keypres function is passed an event that contains the key that was pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to follow code below

```
<body id="bod" onkeypress="keypres(event)">

    <h1 id="txt">hello</h1>    
        
</body>

<script>
    function keypres(event){

        if(event.charCode=='32'){

            document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = event.key;

        }
        else{

            document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML += event.key;

        }
    
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ok this code works but when i want to clear this instead of clearing it it types "Backspace" can you tell me the if functon i would need to clear this instead of getting the "Backspace" written out.

Comment: I am not clear your requirements exactly. May be you have to write something like Backspace value

Comment: you see i have added a plus here `document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML += event.key;` so this gives a sentence instead of giving one letter. So i would want the ability to delete the previous input in the sentence that i've written instead of getting a Backspace when I press the BACKSPACE button on my keyboard.

Comment: When a user press `backspace` button then you delete previous text which he/she write? Do you want this?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i am talking about

Comment: please let me some time

Comment: @knowledgeseeker, Please Check. I update my answer. It works fine what you want. If it is helpful for you please upvote